# how to create dynamic mapping with elasticsearch_dsl

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have to create mapping which should look something like this.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "product_id": {
            "type": "keyword"
        },
        "attributes": {
            "dynamic": "true",
            "properties": {}
        },
    }
}
```

I would normally do something like this

```
class RetailerProductGeneric(Document):
    product_id = Keyword()
```

how do I do it when I have a dynamic schema in the document ?

I looked at the docs but not very clear to me. It goes as follows:

```
class Post(Document):
    title = Text()

    class Meta:
        all = MetaField(enabled=False)
        dynamic = MetaField('strict')
```

not sure what is happening here. Can someone please explain how to do it?

EDIT 1:

After some research, I figured how to create the dynamic mapping.

```
class RetailerProductGeneric(Document):
    product_id = Keyword()
    attributes = Object(dynamic=True)
```

but now expected mapping turns out to be like this

```
  "attributes": {
    "dynamic": true,
    "type": "object"
  },
```

what I am looking for is

```
  "attributes": {
    "dynamic": "true",
    "properties": {}
  },
```

What difference does it make? How Can I make the mapping as expected.

Comment: What additional information do you need that isn't already contained in the answer?

Comment: I think I am good. Thanks a lot :) @Val

Comment: May I ask why you added the bounty to draw more attention then?

Comment: Actually, how to get the dynamic template mapping was my original question, which I eventually figured out. Later I was confused about a part that you answered. 

since I dint get any response in first 2 days, I started bounty.

Comment: I guess it would be unfair to not reward bounty. Your answer did help. So here's your bounty. Thanks once again. :)

Comment: Thanks again, feel free to create a new question if more information is needed ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good start!!

```
"attributes": {
  "dynamic": true,
  "type": "object"
},
```

and

```
"attributes": {
  "dynamic": "true",
  "properties": {}
},
```

are actually exactly the same thing.

When `type: object` is specified, `properties: {}` is implied

And when `properties: {}` is specified and no `type` is given, then `type: object` is implied.